# Using greeks characters and sub-superscript in Win32 with C

Tags: c, winapi

I need to set some labels in an engineering software GUI using greek characters and sub or super-scripts.
Could someone explain me how to do this programming in C with Win32?

Comment: And what are your problems ? Your code ?

Comment: Is your question really "can anyone help me?". In which case the answer to the question that you asked is "yes, there exist people that can help you."

Comment: What a really useful answer, thank you!

Comment: Exactly. Completely useless to you. However, it is the answer to the question that you asked. The point is that it really matters that you ask a precise and specific question. The help you receive will be better if you do so. This requires some investment from you. So, it's now up to you to ask a better question. If you edit the question as described in the close note above we can reopen it and provide you with help.

Comment: I apologize for my error, I changed the question to be more precise and removed all kindness or deceptive words.
I hope now the question is more understandable, thank you.

Comment: What GUI framework, if any are you using? Raw Win32, or something more advanced?

Comment: I'using raw Win32 with pure C.
As I wrote in a comment to the answer below the best way to put some partial formatted text in a GUI seems to be using a rich text editor control in read-only mode, but now the problem is how to properly set text in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to instantiate either a web browser control (very heavy, but understands HTML, which is easy,) or a read-only rich text control. (Which is more lightweight but you will have to learn how to format text in it.)

Comment: Using a rich text control in read only mode sounds like the most practical way to do what I need, but as you said the problem is to set properly control text.
I tried to compose the label text in a rich text editor (like Wordpad), open saved file with an ascii editor, copy the formatted text code and set it via the SetWindowText function, which should work with all windows, but I obtain an error at compiling time.. do you know how to set rich text in a rich text control? thank you a lot!

Comment: Rich edit controls are documented. Start there. There is also windowless rich edit which will look better.

Comment: Whoops, I did not see these comments.  Sorry, Filippo, I have no prior hands-on experience with Rich Edit controls, I only know that they exist and that they can be used for things like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a label, say, `HWND static`, you can set its text via `SetWindowText(static, L"Unicode_text_ффф");`. You might want to explicitly use `SetWindowTextW`, which is the Unicode version of the function.

Comment: I need to write some labels with generic characters as subscripts, unicode has only some chars codified as subscripts and the ones I need are missed.